# Notebook overheating for no reason at all

Tags: 12.04, overheating

HP DV6 6121tx, Ubuntu 12.04

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler XT [AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series]
```

My CPU temp is ~70oC right now, and GPU at around 48oC.

I've switched OFF my discrete AMD gpu via VGASwitcheroo, so it's not a GPU overheat problem.

The issue is that my CPU temps reach ~70-75oC unnecessarily when all I'm doing is just some internet browsing.

I don't even know how to begin to debug this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your Radeon graphics is definitely off and you are only using Intel then maybe installing Jupiter to handle your power management may help:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html

Also, a less 3D intensive version of Ubuntu may help as well which would be less taxing on the graphics card...  Xubuntu is a great alternative...

Last, try updating to the latest Ubuntu 13.04 (or 13.10 in October) as every release has better driver support and newer features that manage the latest hardware better...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source of the problem my monitoring what process is using how much of your CPU power. Just type `top` in the terminal.